# Navigation drawer in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I know this question has been asked multiple times. But my concern is different.

Using [Mr. Tamada Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) I've created a `NavigaionActivity` and multiple `fragments` to replace in `FrameLayout`. It's working fine.

Now, after selecting any option in a fragment, another activity gets open.

**I want the same Navigation menu in that Activity.**

> Navigation view -- fragments -- Activity (display navigation view here)

What I tried:

1. use the `xml` code of displaying `Navigation view` in that activity.
   (DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout etc)

   Then in Activity.java, on click of menu item diverting to the Navigation Activity.

**Code**:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
    ....> 

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
    ....> 

         <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         ....> 

             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             .... /> 

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

         <LinearLayout
         .... /> <!-- main content of this Acitivity-->
   
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>  

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      .... /> 
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity.java:

```
public void dashboard(MenuItem item) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fragment", Constant.DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT);
    UtilityClass.newActivity(this, NavigationActivity.class, bundle);
}
```

And handling the call on Navigation Activity. It is doing the task but code isn't re-usable

2. Create a separate layout file for Navigation and include it in the Activity. But, this is replacing the main content. Here only included Navigation is visible.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downvoters - here the solution is..

1. Create an `xml` file which will have `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` (one can use the xml given in Question, without the main content) - `navigation.xml`
2. As suggested in many answers "create a BaseActivity which `extends` AppCompatActivity. And inflate `navigation.xml`.

   ```
   public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.navigation, null);

           // view declarations
           DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
           ...... }}
   ```
3. In whichever `Activity` you wanna use this `NavigationMenu`, extend BaseActivity for that class.

   ```
   GraphActivity extends BaseActivity { .... }
   ```
4. In `GraphActivity.xml` add the `NavigationMenu` code. You can't just include the `navigation.xml` it will disable the current xml widgets.
5. Done!

Comment: if I use navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this) inside the BaseActivity, it throws an error: "Error:(39, 58) error: incompatible types: BaseActivity cannot be converted to OnNavigationItemSelectedListener". Any advice if you use the standard way that Android Studio inflates an NavigationDrawerActvitiy?

Comment: I've reproduced the error in the baseActivity branch of this minimal example repo: https://github.com/Atticus29/navigationDrawerMCV

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_describtion);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, frameLayout);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Plz Don't use it this way

Instead use Google recommended **MasterDetailFlow Design**

[image: This is MasterDetailFlow]

You can read how to implement this on

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-masterdetail-flow-tutorial-in-android-studio/