# Best way to add navigation drawers to multiple activities that already exist

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in the MainActivity on my app, which I created using the Android Studio IDE.

I also created several other activities as "Empty Activities" using Android Studio. I have fleshed the app out quite a bit, so it would be non-trivial to re-create all of those activities as "Navigation Drawer Activities".

What is the best way to add the same navigation drawer to multiple activities retroactively in this kind of context?

I have an minimal, complete, and verifiable example [here](https://github.com/Atticus29/navigationDrawerMCV). Running it on an emulator in AS, Nexus5X API 25 x86.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Base class that sets NavigationView on onCreate() and create a method to set selected index for each Activity and set index for each activity. To be more clear i advise you to [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118446/5457853).

Comment: @Faith Ozcan thanks for the suggestions. I've tried to implement their answer, but come across some issues:
if I use navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this) inside the BaseActivity, it throws an error: "Error:(39, 58) error: incompatible types: BaseActivity cannot be converted to OnNavigationItemSelectedListener". Any advice if you use the standard way that Android Studio inflates an NavigationDrawerActvitiy?

Comment: I've reproduced the error in the baseActivity branch of this github repository posted in the original question.

Comment: @Atticus29, i will check it out and try to give you answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, @Faith Ozcan